# locked out of my luks volume "Not authorized to perform operation (polkit authority not available and caller is not uid 0)"

Tags: encryption, lvm, luks, policykit, passphrase

For no apparent reason, I can no longer access my LUKS-encrypted volume.

It has been working for months but today on trying to open it in Nautilus, I get a passphrase request (which I didn't before, as it was set to "Remember forever"). I enter the correct passphrase but I get a splash window with the following message:

"Not authorized to perform operation (polkit authority not available and caller is not uid 0)"

Any ideas how to access my drive?

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting did not help. Still getting the request for a passphrase but my passphrase was never accepted.

However, a full shutdown and boot solved the issue. Passphrase was requested and given and this time accepted...